# Create string of Letter and length of a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I would like to create a string, from a letter and length of a string. This is what I currently have, but is there a better way to do this?

```js
function generate(letter, len) {
   var str = '';
   for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
     str+=letter;
   }
  
   return str;
  
}
```

Comment: I think questions like this belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Depends on the js environment (ES6 [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)), available libraries in the environment, what you mean by "better"

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if this is better in terms of performance as some engines optimize the code while others do not. However it's readable, to a javascript programmer.

You can create an array with size `len + 1` and then join it by the letter.

For this, we will make use of array constructor, where we can define the size of the array and `Array.join` to join the array with the given `letter`.

```
function generate(letter, len) {
    return new Array(len + 1).join(letter); 
}
```

Comment: Why is this better? Is it faster? I doubt it. Is is easier to read? That can be discussed to infinity.

Comment: I think it's not better way to join probabily inifinite length of string. by creating array You're creating an object in ram, then You're joining it also consuming resources. Using "for loop" for generating is still better way.

Comment: @AmitJoki You don't know how the engine ( compiler / interpreter ) will handle sting concatenation. Maybe it will use something like the StringBuilder from Java or C#. Maybe it will reserve memory for each string and free it again after it's done being used.

Comment: Maybe it will inspect the code and make a string of length `len` and simply rewrite the concatenation  to `str[i] = letter`.

Comment: @dev-null http://jsperf.com/for-vs-array-join/3 For loop may be faster when the len is small..but what happens when it becomes somewhat big? Talk about micro-optimization

Comment: @AmitJoki Can you please consider checking another engine than V8? And how often do you need a string 20.000.000 chars long?

Comment: @dev-null seems checked in IE and Firefox, seems that they optimize the code while V8 does not. And by the way, my speculation was based on how many objects are initialized. And how often do you need a function that's ultra-fast when most engines already optimize most of the code..and jsperf isn't quite perfect.  I've edited my answer accordingly.